# Add stretched image as div/site background

Tags: html, css, styles

Trying to do this with that code:

```
 #background {
background-image: url(background_image.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

But the problem is that when I scroll down the site there is not image but empty white area. How could I fix it?

Comment: Could you show your markup and a live example reproducing the error?

Comment: did you try background-size: cover;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try this?

```
body {
   background-image: url("background_img.jpg");
   background-size: 100vw 100vh;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

`vw` is viewport width, i.e. the width of the device screen.
`vh` is viewport height, i.e. the height of the device screen.

With the property of `background-size: 100vw 100vh` the background image is automatically going to resize to the size of the users device screen.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)